# How to point Godaddy Domain to Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, dns

I am running a Node.JS HTTP server on an Amazon EC2 instance.

My IP address and port are 54.169.62.98:7001. How do I point my Godaddy domain to this IP and port?

Is it possible to use a port other than 80?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some protocols such as XMPP can use SRV records, which does allow you to publish the port used. However, in the general case, especially web traffic, you can't point an A record to a TCP port.

It sounds like you would want to either get Node to listen on port 80, or install a reverse proxy (such as Nginx) on your EC2 instance to forward traffic on port `80` to `127.0.0.1:7001`. There's a [simple guide here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html#proxy).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, simple.

- Go to godady DNS manager and add a type A record pointing to your ip address like bellow.[image]
- Then go to your aws-ec2 console and add a custom inbound TCP rule under your AWS security group like bellow.
  [image]
- Open firewall for 7001/tcp on your server `sudo ufw allow 7001/tcp`
- Run the node.js app on your server and then type 54.169.62.98:7001 on your browser

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
Yes, you can point any instance of AWS via GoDaddy domain. You have to save A record for hit your instance via host @ and point to your IP(54.169.62.98), after this you can hit you IP but not port 7001, for port distribution you will have to some config some file.
```

> for Virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyRequests Off
ServerName www.example.org
ServerAlias example.org
Redirect permanent / https://example.org/
</VirtualHost>
```

> For ssl config

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
      <VirtualHost *:443>
              ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
              ServerName example.org
              DocumentRoot /var/www/html
              ProxyPreserveHost On
              ProxyRequests Off
              ProxyPass / http://localhost:7001/
              ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:7001/
              ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
              CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
              SSLEngine on
              SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
              SSLCertificateFile /home/ubuntu/today.crt
              SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/ubuntu/today.key
              SSLCertificateChainFile /home/ubuntu/intermediate.crt
              SSLCACertificateFile /home/ubuntu/intermediate.crt
              <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                              SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
              </FilesMatch>
              <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                              SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
              </Directory>
              BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
                              nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
                              downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
              BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown
      </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```